# What causes my mcu to blow up when hooking up with oscilloscope?

Tags: microcontroller, oscilloscope, mains, grounding

I was observing some timer signals yesterday, earlier in the morning I had my oscilloscope on another lab workbench where I would first make some changes, reflash the board and then take it to that workbench to observe, while providing power use a switchable microusb cord connected to a usb wall connector. Like the setup shown here :

Updates : I was probing a SMT LED.


Nothing went wrong
[image: SuccessfulSetup]

However, I was getting kinda lazy running back & forth so I thought maybe I could just have it connected to my PC so I can observe it right after flashing. So I hooked everything up, and then turned on the oscilloscope...and as soon as I pressed the power button, "zap" went my MCU, with a bit of smoke as well.

Setup shown here :
[image: FailedSetup]

After some googling, I think it was maybe something to do with the scenario shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaELqAo4kkQ) (which is also the reference for my drawing), can anyone kindly help me figure out what the actual cause is? Though I have lots of spare boards, I still wanted to know how I can prevent this while also learn what had happened. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you connect your scope ground clip to anything not ground? What is that connection on bottom left of the ESK32?

Comment: @DKNguyen It's a SMT LED, no I didn't clip anything not ground...

Comment: Then what is the ground clip doing on the + of the LED?

Comment: @JohnnyYeng - The diagrams are helpful. However, I believe your diagrams are slightly wrong. I think this is the same issue referred to by *DKNguyen* above. On the left side of both diagrams, the two connections to the oscilloscope are *the wrong way round*. The **lower** of the two wires going to the BNC connector is the earth (it goes to "Mains Earth" in the bottom left corner), but you show the *upper* of the two BNC wires going to "GND" on your board. I guess (?) it's the diagrams which are wrong and not your physical wiring. However the diagrams will confuse people in their current state.

Comment: @SamGibson Oh I see what your saying..as a matter of fact...my diagram was not drawn wrong as it was how I wired the setup, but this does indeed point out that something's clearly wrong 

Comment: @SamGibson I think I kinda know whats going wrong here... Here's my hypothesis : I had normal readings in the first place because the power source was a two prong which didn't share main earth as ground, but when I hooked it up to the PC, I shorted vcc to ground. Am I correct?

Comment: @JohnnyYeng - Hi, I can't properly think about this question now (it's past bedtime here in the UK). Your comment is the *type* of situation I'd expect to cause a problem, except you said in the question that the "trigger" for the MCU damage was *switching-on* the scope. Now you are talking about when it was hooked-up to the earthed PC. I can explain one, but not the other. Personally, I'd want to see photos of the real hardware, to avoid possible misunderstandings and wasted time describing a hypothesis which doesn't match the hardware. Perhaps someone else will answer even without photos...

Comment: What brand/model is your scope?

Comment: @BruceAbbott GWINSTEK GDS-2062 (It's a discontinued product btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have a ground issue on your board (non-continuous ground that is linked through the MCU) or somewhat connected the ground of the scope where it shouldn't be.

Your PC is most certainly grounded (sometimes, for laptops, it can be grounded in unintuitive ways through an external screen and through HDMI cables for example).

Your scope and computer are likely not connected to the same socket, you can be on a different line and thus have a voltage difference between the grounds which is probably caused by induced voltage.

This happened to me 2 weeks ago, as I found out that the ground between 2 adjacent sockets in my office had 100 V difference! My board was connected to my laptop (grounded through the screen) and a scope on another socket. Screen went black, it almost killed my laptop and my electronics, trying to understand when I finally went to measure the earth line on the sockets.